# LLDB for Swift: Custom type summary for generic type

Tags: swift, lldb

With LLDB I can add custom summaries for a type:

```
(lldb) type summary add -s "This is a Foo" Baz.Foo
```

However, I am unable to do this for a generic type with two or more generics.

Given a module Baz with the type `Foo` that has two or more generics:

```swift
struct Foo<Bar: Numeric, Bar2: Numeric> {}
```

I have tried the following; all without success:

- `type summary add -s "This is a Foo" Baz.Foo`
- `type summary add -s "This is a Foo" Baz.Foo<A, B>`
- `type summary add -s "This is a Foo" Baz.Foo<Float, Float>`
- `type summary add -s "This is a Foo" Baz.Foo<Bar, Bar2>`
- `type summary add -s "This is a Foo" Baz.Foo<Float>`

In all cases, the standard description was being printed instead of the custom one.

So how can I add a custom summary for a generic type with two or more generics, ideally without having to specify concrete types for `Bar` and `Bar2`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the summary feature, but it is capable of calling methods on the value? If so, you could make a make a summary something like `CustomDebugStringConvertible` and have `Foo` implement it with the desired `debugDescription`

Comment: It is possible to load a Python script in LLDB, which would evaluate the `debugDescription` or `description` properties when using the `fr v` command (and maybe the `p` command), which is actually my end goal. With `type summary add -s "whatever" Module.Type`, I can successfully target non-generic types or types with exactly one generic parameter. However, my issue is that this does not seem to work for types with two or more generic type parameters.

Comment: Can you target the `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol type itself, and have all of the conforming types (incl your generic `Foo<Bar, Bar2>`) pick up that same summary?

Comment: This only works when I use `p value as CustomStringConvertible` for the first time printing a value of any type after defining the type summary. After that, it works without `as CustomStringConvertible`. Also, this does not work from an `~/.lldbinit` file. So while this gets me closer to my goal, it is not 100% there.

Comment: If I use a custom marker protocol (e.g. `protocol FooProtocol {}`) instead of `CustomStringConvertible`, I can make it work from my `~/.lldbinit` file, but it still requires the initial cast.

Comment: @Palle I have to ask: how did you manage to call `description` through Python? `SBValue` seems to be able to access only stored properties

Comment: I had this [exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62398294/2557145) myself. The answer is to evaluate an expression on the target with `value.GetTarget().EvaluateExpression(value.GetName() + ".yourProperty")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `--regex`/`-x` flag to pattern match generic types in Swift, or template types in C++.

```
type summary add -s "This is a Foo" -x "^Baz\.Foo<.+,.+>$"
```

You can see many examples by running `type summary list -l swift`. Here's how `Dictionary` is shown:

```
^Swift\.Dictionary<.+,.+>$:  (show children) (hide value) (skip references) Swift.Dictionary summary provider
```