# LLDB for Swift: Access computed property or perform function call in type summary Python script

Tags: swift, lldb

When I create a custom type summary using a Python script, it is possible to access ivars using `value.GetChildMemberByName("<child-name>")`. However, this does not work for computed properties or functions.

With the `frame variable` command, the script that generates the summary can evaluate expressions in the current frame (e.g. `value.GetFrame().EvaluateExpression(value.GetName() + ".description")`)

However, this will not work when using `p <some-expression>`/`expression -- <some-expression>` as there is no frame, so the above statement will fail to produce any results.

Is there a way to call functions or evaluate computed properties in a type summary when using `p` (`expression --`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EvaluateExpression`  function is available on the target as well as on frames. Try `value.GetTarget().EvaluateExpression(...)`.

Comment: This is great when using Xcode but unfortunately it does not seem to work in the Swift REPL. There, I am getting the error `error: <user expression 0>:1:1: use of undeclared identifier '$R0'` when evaluating `value.GetName() + ".description"` on the target.

Answer (score 2):

You might what to use SBValue.CreateValueFromExpression instead of either the frame or the target EvaluateExpression calls for data formatters.

SBValues remember the context they were defined in, and SBValue.CreateValueFromExpression funnels that context back to the expression evaluator.  Since the Variable formatters always receive the SBValue that they are acting on, CreateValueFromExpression allows a simple way to forward that context to the new expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had no luck with `CreateValueFromExpression` when using `expression --` / `p`. When I evaluate `value.CreateValueFromExpression("description", value.GetName() + ".description").GetSummary()`, `GetSummary()` returns `None`. Is there any special way I have to refer to `value` in the expression?

Comment: What error do you get from the expression?  You can see that by capturing the result of value.CreateValueFromExpression in a temporary variable, and running `tmpvar.GetError().GetCString()`.

Comment: `error: <user expression 1>:1:1: use of undeclared identifier '$R11'`.

Comment: Yup, I saw that one too.  Looks like there's a problem with the context that's set in the expression result value objects.  At least in my tests, in `frame var variableOfMyType` and thus in the Xcode locals view, CreateValueFromExpression worked.  But it fails when the incoming value is the result of an expression.  I filed a bug with Apple's bug reporter about that.